# issues with expect -send: spawn id exp4 not open

Tags: unix, send, expect

My expect code does this: It does a ssh connect to another machine, sends the password and then returns the hostname of that machine. I give a sample of my code below 
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set ipaddr [lrange $argv 0 0]
set password [lrange $argv 1 1]
set timeout -1
spawn ssh root@$ipaddr hostname
match_max 100000
expect "*assword:*"
send -- "$password\r"
expect eof
This code runs perfectly many times but intermittently, I get the following error 
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send -- "$password\r""
Why is this happening?

Comment: `send: spawn id exp4 not open` implies that the `ssh root@$ipaddr hostname` has failed or closed before the `send` can complete.

Comment: what I'd like to know is how to check the spawn id to see if it's open or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out why.
I had generated ssh keys and copied it on to the destination machine. So there was no "Password: " prompt. Hence before send could complete, the ssh connection had closed.

I deleted the ssh keys from the destination machine and ran the script again and observed no issues

Comment: I still have a question about that. If you generated ssh key, you should meet this problem every time, not intermittently.